# My code won't run if values over four are entered

Tags: java

This code converts from meters to feet/inches/kilometers. Sorry, I know this is basic, I'm new to Java. When prompted for a number of meters, if 4 or over is entered it doesn't convert and ends the program. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Measurements
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Have user make selection
    String input;
    int selectedNum;  // number chosen
    float numMeters; // number of meters
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a distance in meters."); 
    numMeters = Float.parseFloat(input); 
    menu(); 
    selectedNum = Integer.parseInt(input); 
  // Selection results
    if (selectedNum < 1 )
    { errorMessage(); }
    if (selectedNum == 1)
    { showKilometers(numMeters); }
    if (selectedNum == 2)
    { showInches(numMeters); }
    if (selectedNum == 3)
    { showFeet(numMeters); }
    if (selectedNum == 4)
    { 
      exitSystem();
    } 

  }


  /** errorMessage method */
  public static double errorMessage()
  {
    double selectedNum;
    String input; 
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("That is not a valid selection. Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4."); 
    selectedNum = Integer.parseInt(input);
    return selectedNum; 
  }
  /** menu method */
  public static String menu()
  {
    String input; 
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a selection:\n1. Convert to kilometers\n2. Convert to inches\n3. Convert "
                                   + "to feet\n4. Quit the program."); 
    return input;
  }
  /** showKilometers method */
  public static void showKilometers(double numMeters)
  {
    double result; 
    result = numMeters*.001; 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numMeters + " meters is " + result + " kilometers.");
  }
  /** showInches method */
  public static void showInches(double numMeters)
  {
    double inches; 
    inches = numMeters*(39.37);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numMeters + " meters is " + inches + " inches.");
  }
  /** showFeet */
  public static void showFeet(double numMeters)
  {
    double awesome; 
    awesome = (3.281*numMeters);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numMeters + " meters is " + awesome + " feet.");
  }
  public static void exitSystem()
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }

}
```

Comment: Just a tip: In order to learn, it is often better to try to write your own code than to modify someone else's; you need quite some experience to understand how other programmers code.

Answer (score 2):

The `String input` in `menu()` is a different variable from the `String input` in `main`.

The `menu` function should be `return`ing the value for `selectedNum` to use. Once that fix is made,

```
menu(); 
selectedNum = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

should be changed to:

```
selectedNum = Integer.parseInt(menu());
```

Comment: Please update your code above. Otherwise I can't look at it and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

The input return from menu() is not the input in main, the input in main is always refer to the input of "Enter a distance in meters.", that is the reason why when user enter number of meters >=4 the program either exit or show error. Besides, I would prefer using switch than if else for condition switching scenario;

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    double numMeters = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a distance in meters.")); 

    switch(menu()) {
        case 1:
            showKilometers(numMeters);
            break;
        case 2: 
            showInches(numMeters);
            break;
        case 3;
           showFeet(numMeters);
           break;
        case 4;
           exitSystem();
           break;
        default;
           errorMessage();
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
selectedNum = menu();
```

instead of

```
menu(); 
selectedNum = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

since the menu() function is already return integer value, no need to parse it.

however you can use switch statement as in this code

```
switch (selectedNum){
case 1: showKilometers(numMeters);
case 2: showInches(numMeters);
case 3: showFeet(numMeters);
case 4: exitSystem();
default: errorMessage();
}
```